# What am I doing wrong on this simple Closure

Tags: javascript, closures, dom-events

It maybe sleep deprivation but I cannot understand why this isn't working. I want the `onclick` to return the value of `i` from a for loop that created the element and applied the event handler. Have put it in a closure and it is still turning the max number of the iterator.

```
window.onload = function(){
  var arbitrary_amount = 100;
  var the_list = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
  
  for(var i = 0; i < arbitrary_amount; i++){
    var natural_index = i + 1;
    var list_item = document.createElement('li');
    var inner_link = document.createElement('a');
    inner_link.setAttribute('href', '#');
    inner_link.innerHTML = "Link "+natural_index;
    
    inner_link.onclick = function(){
      return function(link_num){
        alert('You clicked link '+link_num);
      }(i);
    };
    
    list_item.appendChild(inner_link);
    the_list.appendChild(list_item);
  }
  
  
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you are using the closure in the wrong way...i can't give you a guru type answer as to what was actually happening but here is a working (didn't test it) closure:

```
inner_link.onclick = (function(link_num){
   return function(){
       alert('You clicked link '+link_num);
   };
})(i);
```

Comment: The guru type answer is: the `i` was being captured by a closure which is then passed to a self-calling function inside the event handler function. That is not what was desired. Instead the `i` should be passed by value into a self-calling function which returns an event handler function which captures the `link_num` as closure. Hmm.. should I consider putting this in an answer instead of this comment?

Comment: ahh...i see...i understand why i was confused. the outer function was being used as an event handler because it wasn't a self-calling function. Therefore the it captured the last value of i.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var arbitrary_amount = 100;
  var the_list = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];

  for(var i = 0; i < arbitrary_amount; i++){
    (function(){var natural_index = i + 1;
    var list_item = document.createElement('li');
    var inner_link = document.createElement('a');
    inner_link.setAttribute('href', '#');
    inner_link.innerHTML = "Link "+natural_index;

    inner_link.onclick = function(){
      return function(link_num){
        alert('You clicked link '+link_num);
      }(i);
    };

    list_item.appendChild(inner_link);
    the_list.appendChild(list_item);})();
  }


};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works correctly for me in Firefox 3.5.5 and Chrome 4.0.249.64.

Answer (score 0):

It's because each closure you create for the onclick handler shares the same environment. When the `onclick` callback function is executed, each one refers to the last value of `i`.

There are already various solutions out, so I won't repeat it here, but the idea is to create additional closures that do not share the same environment.

It's a common mistake. Checkout this [MDC article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3a_A_common_mistake) for more insights.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">


<head>


<title>Just testing</title>


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />


</head>
<body>



<div id="test1">
Testing
</div>




<script type="text/javascript">


//  self-invoking function


(function makeHR(){
      var newHR = document.createElement('hr');
      document.getElementById('test1').appendChild(newHR);
})();





function makeLink(j){


      var link =document.createElement("a");


  link.innerHTML ="<br>Link test " +j;


  link.setAttribute('href', '#');

  link.onclick = (function(link_num){


   return function(){


   alert('You clicked link '+link_num);

   };


  })(j);

  document.body.appendChild(link);
}


for (var i=1; i<4; i++) {

   makeLink(i);

}


</script>


</body>

</html>
```